# Maior palíndromo em uma string? C++

Tags: c++

Estou tentando fazer um código para conseguir descobrir, por exemplo se em frases como:
A arara azul é linda! 
tem um palindromo e qual é o maior deles?
no caso a resposta seria:
arara
Cheguei no código abaixo mas não sei como desenvolver ele para conseguir a solução. Alguém pode me ajudar? Gostaria que me quem puder me ajudar explique como chegou nessa lógica para que eu possa entender. Obrigado.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    string frase; // Guarda uma string

    bool ok = true; // Ajuda a verificar se a variável é um palíndrormo


    getline(cin,frase); // Recebe a frase que será tratada.

    int tam = frase.size(); // Atribui na variável tam o tamanho da string: frase.

    for (int i = 0, j = tam - 1 ; i < tam - 1; i++, j--){

        if( frase[i] == frase[j] ){
            ok = true;
        }else{
            ok = false;
        }

    }

        if( ok == true ){
            cout << "E palindromo" <<  endl;
        }else{
            cout << "Nao e palindromo" << endl;
        }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Dica: tenta com o [algoritmo de Manacher](https://cp-algorithms.com/string/manacher.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O código a baixo faz a busca em uma frase pela sequencia de caracteres que formem um palíndromo, desde que a frase não use virgula ou acentuação, para este caso basta você inclui uma verificação a cada rodada do for na string `sub_sentence`.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool check_palindrome(string sentence) {

    string sentence_without_space;

    //Isto é necessário caso queira vê palidromes de várias palavras em uma frase
    for (int i = 0; i < sentence.size(); i++) {

        if (sentence[i] == ' ') {

            continue;
        }

        //Removendo os espaços em branco
        sentence_without_space.push_back(sentence[i]);
    }

    //Verificando se é palindrome
    for (int i = 0, j = sentence_without_space.size() - 1; i <= j; i++, j--) {

        if (sentence_without_space[i] != sentence_without_space[j]) {

            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}


string analyze_sentence(string sentence) {

    string greater_palindrome;
    string sub_sentence;
    string sub_sentence_palindrome;
    //---

    //Normaliza a entrada de dados
    for (int i = 0; i < sentence.size(); i++) {

        sentence[i] = tolower(sentence[i]);
    }

    //Percorre toda a sequencia de caracteres da frase, comparando se há um palindrome a partir do caracter atual
    for (int i = 0; i < sentence.size(); i++) {

        //Caso o caracter inicial seja fazio ignora e não verifica
        if (sentence[i] == ' ')
            continue;

        //Selecionando a senquancia de busca atual
        sub_sentence = sentence.substr(i);

        //Percorre do final para o inicio verificando se o conjunto de caracteres entre os indices i e j formam um palindrome
        for (int j = sub_sentence.size(); j > 0; j--) {

            //Caso o caracter final seja fazio ignora e não verifica
            if (sub_sentence[j] == ' ')
                continue;

            //Extrai o possível palindrome
            sub_sentence_palindrome = sub_sentence.substr(0, j);

            //Verifica se é um palindrome
            if (check_palindrome(sub_sentence_palindrome)) {

                //Sendo um palindrome verifica e salva o de maior tamanho
                if (sub_sentence_palindrome.size() > greater_palindrome.size()) {

                    greater_palindrome = sub_sentence_palindrome;
                }
                break; //Aqui você pode encerrar a busca pois este for só irá decrementar o J e procurar por coisa menores ao palindrome atual
            }
        }
    }

    return greater_palindrome;
}

int main() {

    string greater_palindrome = analyze_sentence("Enquanto ele estava seco de raiva coloco no colo caviar e doces!");

    printf("%s\n", greater_palindrome.c_str());

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

O código está bastante comentado acredito que será fácil entender. De uma forma geral analiso todas as sequencias de caracteres a partir do primeiro índice da frase e sempre decrementando o tamanho da sequencia investigada. Por exemplo, na frase 'A arara azul é linda!' começo analisando tudo em seguida decremento o tamanho da string em 1 e ai a minha busca fica na string 'A arara azul é linda', em seguida 'A arara azul é lind', e assim sucessivamente. Após fazer isso, me baseado no início da string sendo a primeira posição, incremento o índice de início da sequencia de caracteres e faço a busca a partir de 'arara azul é linda!', e continuo decrementando o tamanho dessa analise em 'arara azul é linda'. Sempre que é formado uma nova sequencia para ser avaliada se é ou não um palíndromo eu verifico o tamanho do palíndromo para salvar apenas a de maior tamanho.

Obs.: O comentário de Mário sobre o algoritmo de Manacher deve ser interessante, pois deve ser algo mais otimizado, não cheguei a ler.

Comment: Obrigado Lucas Arruda! Você me ajudou muito. Vou estudar o código e estudar a lógica. Acredite em min, você me ajudou muito. Obrigado e sucesso nos seus objetivos :)